# How to Fill ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, color

Given a contour plot such as

```
function = Cos[c] + Cos[a]
pltc = ContourPlot[function == 1/2, {a, 0, 4 Pi}, {c, 0, 4 Pi}];
```

How can I color the regions in which `function > 1/2` one color and `function < 1/2` another color?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(47897)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47897/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ContourPlot[Cos[c] + Cos[a], {a, 0, 4 Pi}, {c, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 Contours -> {1/2}, ContourShading -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

you can also use `RegionPlot`

```
RegionPlot[{function <= 1/2, function > 1/2}, {a, 0, 4 Pi}, {c, 0, 
  4 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image]